# IKEv2 certificate error but SSTP successfully connects Windows 10 pro / Windows Server 2019

Tags: vpn, remote-access, windows-server-2019, sstp, ikev2

I'm using Windows server 2019 (installed roles: AD DC, CA, DHCP, DNS, IIS, VPN).
my client is Windows 10 pro.

before installing the Online responder role and having a CRL server, IkEv2 was working, but after installing and configuring that role (in order to use SSTP, since it needs to check for CRL), IKEv2 stopped working and gives me this error:

[image]

**so now SSTP is working but IKEv2 does not work.**

I also should mention that before setting up online responder role, I tried enabling Direct Access on my server just for a test and set it up half way (went through the wizard and installed group policy, certificates etc.) but then i decided to remove it so i used the Remote Access Management Console to remove the installed Direct Access and VPN, restarted server and set up my only my VPN server again.
at this point I installed the online responder and the rest of the story i mentioned above.

I don't know what happened because before enabling and removing DA, IKEv2 was working but SSTP wasn't, now SSTP is working but IKEv2 isn't.
(of course the reason why SSTP wasn't working was because i hadn't setup online responder and published CRL so when SSTP was checking for revocation list it was failing).

I tried going through all my setups again and again but can't find anything problematic. i would appreciate if anyone can help me find the origin of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This [Technet Article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rrasblog/2009/06/10/what-type-of-certificate-to-install-on-the-vpn-server/) was really helpful in solving my problem

The reason why I was getting that error was because I added 2 CN to my certificate when requesting in on CA/VPN server (FQN and the Server's private IP address)SSTP was OK with it but IKEv2 wasn't. so I removed the IP address and only added the FQN to the common name, that's it problem solved. I don't know if it's a Server 2019 thing or what, I watched a video on YouTube and someone actually did that on windows Server 2016 and added both IP and FQN when requesting certificate on the CA/VPN server, then he could successfully connect to both IKEv2 and SSTP from his Windows 10 clients.